# What is the characteristic function of a p.d.f with $\mathbb{R}^+$ support?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Considering a generic p.d.f. $p(x)$, we know that the characteristic of such distribution is given by $\varphi(t)=E[e^{i t x}]$. Here $t,x\in (-\infty,\infty)$.

Now I would like to ask what is the characteristic function of a p.d.f. where its support is not the whole real numbers, for instance, the support is $\mathbb{R}^+$.

I already understand that as follows: Assume a two dimensional distribution $f(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with characteristic function $E[e^{i(k_x x+k_y y)}]$. By using polar coordinates $x=r \cos \theta$ and $x=r \sin \theta$ and averaging over $\theta$ we find
$$ p(r)=r\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta\, f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta). $$
Now the support of the distribution $p(r)$ is $\mathbb{R}^+$. In addition, we can average out the characteristic function too,
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} E\left[ \int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\, e^{i r k\cos(\theta-\theta_k)}\right]=E[J_0(k\, r)],$$
where in the above $k_x=k \cos \theta_k$ and $k_y=k \sin \theta_k$. In the above, $J_0(k\, r)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind. In other words, I think the characteristic function for a general distribution $p(r)$ with $\mathbb{R}^+$ is $E[J_0(k\, r)]$.

I am not sure that the above conclusion is true. And if it is true I am not sure it is unique. Also what is the systematic way to find the above result?

Comment: I am a bit confused, do you mean the support of the pdf?

Comment: I am sorry if I am not familiar with the mathematical language. I am physicist. Actually, I mean the domain of the probability distribution $p(x)$.

Comment: Just to be on the same page, in case of the standard normal you would be interested in ${\displaystyle p(x)={\frac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }}}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}x^{2}}}$

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. A pdf supported on R+ is a particular case of a pdf supported on all of R, so its characteristic function is already well defined.

Comment: Mike Hawk: So you say the characteristic function is same as before? Should I set simply the lower bound of the integration in $E[e^{i t x}]$ to zero?

Comment: @Farid: Yes, there's no need for a separate definition in this case (unless perhaps there is some additional context to your question)

Comment: @ user190080 and Mike Hawk: Could you check another related question I posted in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690666/is-a-two-dimensional-rotationally-symmetric-probability-density-function-equival?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just focusing on your primary problem without going into your example (I am afraid I don't quite follow there - maybe you can add some context there), the easiest example I can imagine is the uniform distribution $X\sim\mathcal U[a,b]$. If we choose $0<a<b\in \mathbb R$, we get a distribution which has mass only in $[a,b]$ with $\rm pdf$ (probability density function)
$$
p(x)={\begin{cases}{\frac {1}{b-a}}&\mathrm {for} \ a\leq x\leq b,\\[8pt]0&\mathrm {for} \ x<a\ \mathrm {or} \ x>b\end{cases}}
$$ 
This implies for the characteristic function $\varphi(x)$ (which always exists for all probability distributions), that we get for $t\in \mathbb R$
$$
\varphi_X(t)=E[e^{i t X}]=\int_{\mathbb R}e^{i t x}p(x)dx=\frac 1{b-a}\int_{a}^be^{i t x}dx={\displaystyle {\frac {\mathrm {e} ^{itb}-\mathrm {e} ^{ita}}{it(b-a)}}}
$$
Again, this is the easiest example I can think of, but in general, there is no problem whatsoever with your $\rm pdf$ having support not on the whole real line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In fact, the characteristic function $E[J_0(k\,r]$ is widely  used in a group of physicists who work on heavy ion collisions. But I do not understand it. At the moment a difference I can see is that $E[J_0(k\,r]$ is function of $k\in [0,\infty)$ while $t$ in your case is defined in $\mathbb{R}$. [p.s. I am trying to improve my question]

Comment: @Farid sure thing. A small advice: It might be better to ask several questions if you have several problems, you can always link those questions for reference. So maybe one question on the general nature of characteristic functions and another one (with possibly a reference to the paper) on the specific nature of the heavy ion collision problem.