# Is a two dimensional rotationally symmetric probability density function equivalent to a radial one dimensional density function??

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume that $f(x,y)$ is a two dimensional rotationally symmetric p.d.f.,  $f(x,y)=\tilde{f}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$. In the polar coordinates, $x=r \cos\varphi$, $y=r\sin\varphi$, we can average out the azimuthal angle to find a ***one dimensional radial p.d.f*** as follows,
$$ p(r)= r\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\varphi\, \tilde{f}(r)=2\pi r\, \tilde{f}(r).\qquad\qquad\qquad \qquad     (1)$$

The generating function of the distribution $f(x,y)$ is written as $\mathbb{E}[e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}}]$ where $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)$ and $\mathbf{k}=(k_x,k_y)$ are two dimensional vectors. Here $\mathbb{E}[\cdots]=\int dx dy \cdots \,f(x,y)$. Then the generating function for a rotationally symmetric distribution is given by
$$  \mathbb{E}[e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}}]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}r dr d\varphi\,e^{i k r \cos(\varphi-\varphi_k)}\tilde{f}(r)=2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}r dr\, \tilde{f}(r)\,J_0(kr)=\int_0^{\infty} dr\, p(r) J_0(k r), $$
where in the above $k=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}$ and $\varphi_k=\text{atan2}(k_x,k_y)$ and $J_0(x)$ is the modified Bessel-Function of the first kind. If I define the averaging with respect to $p(r)$ as $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[\cdots]=\int_0^{\infty} dr\cdots p(r)$ then we have the following:
$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{i\mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{x}}] \equiv \tilde{\mathbb{E}}[J_0(k r)]=1-\frac{1}{4}k^2\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[r^2]+\frac{1}{64}k^4\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[r^4]+\cdots\,.$$

**Question:** Based on the above, the characteristic function of a 2D rotationally symmetric p.d.f. can be obtained only from even moments ( $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[r^{2k}]$) of the p.d.f. $p(r)$ which is defined in the range $[0,\infty)$. On the other hand, the characteristic function of $p(r)$ can be written as  $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[e^{i t r}]$ where $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$([What is the characteristic function of a p.d.f with $\mathbb{R}^+$ support?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689746/what-is-the-characteristic-function-of-a-p-d-f-with-mathbbr-support)). It simply means that  $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[r^{2k+1}]$ are moments of $p(r)$ too. Now I am a bit confused. If I know all $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[r^{2k}]$ then I know $f(x,y)$. However, in order to know $p(r)$ I should know about $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[r^{k}]$ for odd $k$  as well as even $k$. On the other hand, $f(x,y)$ and $p(r)$ are uniquelly related to each other from equation (1).

**My Guess:** I think I am missing something obvious! My guess is that $p(r)$ and rotatinaly symmetric $f(x,y)$ are not equivalent, and I can use them interchangeably if I replace the characteristic function  $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[e^{i t r}]$ to  $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[J_0(k r)]$ for $p(r)$.

Comment: If the moments $E(r^{2k})$ determine the distribution of $r^2$ then they also determine the distribution of $r$ since the former determines the latter, for example through the identity $$P(r^2\geqslant t)=P(r\geqslant\sqrt t)$$ for every nonnegative $t$. In particular, the even moments of $r$ then determine its odd moments.

Comment: @ Did: Do you mean that the distribution $p(r)$ for $r\geq 0$ only has even (or equivalently odd) moments? Referring to my question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689746/what-is-the-characteristic-function-of-a-p-d-f-with-mathbbr-support, is the characteristic function defined by $\tilde{\mathbb{E}}[J_0(r k)]$ for such a case?

Comment: "Do you mean that the distribution p(r) for r≥0 only has even (or equivalently odd) moments?" How can one deduce from my comment that I would mean that (which, by the way, is nonsensical) frankly escapes me. Sorry.

Comment: @Did: I am not expert in mathematics. What I got from your comment is that even moments are enough to reproduce $p(r)$ and there is no extra information in odd moments. I understand that my response was misleading.